# How to print patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a pattern from a group of numbers which denotes the direction of flow:

```
0 - north
1 - north east
2 - east
3 - south east
4 - south
5 - south west
6 - west
7 - north west
```

e.g. if 424222006 is the given number, then according to direction i have to print as shown below

```
0 * * 0 0
0 0 * * 0
* 0 0 0 0
```

[image: Picture example]

Comment: You'll probably need to both edit your post to improve the formatting of the output, and be a little clearer when describing how your output depends on the input.

Comment: In addition to that, OP should post some code as a [mcve], otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: Dear fellow members, I added a photo that define how the pattern was achieved.

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework"

Answer (score -1):

You've asked a fairly basic algorithmic design question. In other words, there's no real way to do this other than figuring it out, step by step. Here's my take on it, but it's subject to certain constraints. For example, if you need to dynamically generate a path and extents, you're going to have to at least modify this code, and more likely choose a different approach entirely. (For example, you could preset your extents and clamp the user's moves so that, let's say, if they made a move with an eastward component when they were against the east wall, you tell them they "bumped into something" and then map 'ne' and 'se' to 'n' and 's', respectively, and map 'e' to a no-op.)

```py
from typing import Tuple, List

direction_dict = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(['n', 'ne', 'e', 'se', 's', 'sw', 'w', 'nw'])}


def coordinate_for(coordinate: Tuple, direction: str):
    # for printing, we have row-major coordinates
    if direction == 'n':
        return coordinate[0] - 1, coordinate[1]
    if direction == 'ne':
        return coordinate[0] - 1, coordinate[1] + 1
    if direction == 'e':
        return coordinate[0], coordinate[1] + 1
    if direction == 'se':
        return coordinate[0] + 1, coordinate[1] + 1
    if direction == 's':
        return coordinate[0] + 1, coordinate[1]
    if direction == 'sw':
        return coordinate[0] + 1, coordinate[1] - 1
    if direction == 'w':
        return coordinate[0], coordinate[1] - 1
    if direction == 'nw':
        return coordinate[0] - 1, coordinate[1] - 1


def path_for(origin: Tuple[int, int], directions: str = None):
    path_list = [origin]
    if directions is None:
        return path_list

    for d in directions:
        path_list.append(coordinate_for(path_list[-1], direction_dict[int(d)]))

    return path_list


def extents(path_list: List[Tuple[int, int]]):
    row_indices = [c[0] for c in path_list]
    column_indices = [c[1] for c in path_list]
    min_row = min(row_indices)
    max_row = max(row_indices)
    min_col = min(column_indices)
    max_col = max(column_indices)

    ex = ((min_row, min_col), (max_row, max_col))

    return ex


def drawable_path(field: Tuple[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int]], path_list: List[Tuple[int, int]],
                  field_char: str = '*', path_char: str = '0'):
    drawing = []
    for row_index in range(field[0][0], field[1][0] + 1):
        drawing.append([])
        for column_index in range(field[0][1], field[1][1] + 1):
            drawing[-1].append(path_char if (row_index, column_index) in path_list else field_char)
    return drawing


direction_str = '424222006'

pl = path_for((0, 0), direction_str)
ex = extents(pl)
drawable = drawable_path(ex, pl)

for line in drawable:
    print(''.join(line))
```

Placed in a file called scratch.py in the right location, this yields:

```
>>> from scratch import*
0**00
00**0
*0000
```

The code is pretty quick & dirty. You could, for example, map `'n'`, `'s'`, `'e'`, and `'w'` to operations that bump an integer, then map composites like `'ne'` to their components, and then make shorter work of `coordinate_for` by parsing, for example, 'ne' `into (ops[direction](coordinate), ops[direction](coordinate))` or something. Definitely an exercise for the reader.

As a hint about getting started yourself on algorithmic design problems like this one in the future, consider the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as less advice about asking your question than about solving your problem. Had you broken down the problem into finer-grained or more precise questions, you likely would have found the answer yourself. Think, "With an x-coordinate of 1, moving south should change the x-coordinate to 2," and so on. As your question is asked right now, an actual answer to it could have been: "Given '424...', simply print("0**00\n..." It would have been snarky, but it would have been a valid answer. It's in the clarification and refinement that the algorithm emerges.

Comment: Thanks mike that's a great advice and your program gave me good insights.

Comment: @RohitMallampati, if you want to mark it as the answer, then, that helps me.